# проблема с наследованием php

Tags: php, mysqli

Я не очень знаком с php и сейчас делаю простую админку по видеоуроку, в самом начале возникли проблемы, код перечитывал уже десяток раз, все как на видео 1в1, но не получается сделать запрос к бд.

Код файла database.php

```
<?php 
class Database {
  private $host='localhost';
  private $user="admin";
  private $pass="12345";
  private $db="db2";

  function connectToDb() {
     if($conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user,$this->pass)) {

        if($db=mysqli_select_db($conn,$this->db)) {

        }
     }
  }
  function closeConnection() {
    mysqli_close();
  }
}
?>
```

Код файла select.php

```
<?php 
class Select extends Database{

  private $tabname;
  function __construct($tablename) {
    $this->connectToDb();
    $this->tabname = $tablename;
  }

  function getRecordById($id) {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->tabname WHERE id = '$id'";
        if($sql=mysqli_query($query)){
            $data=mysqli_fetch_array();
        }
        return $data;
  }

  function getAllData() {

  }
}
?>
```

Выводит сообщение об ошибке:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in E:\OpenServer\domains\admin\models\select.php on line 12

У автора видео все работает отлично, подскажите пожалуйста почему я получаю ошибку?

Comment: У автора ролика работает `mysqli_query($query)` ? Найдите другие ролики.

Comment: в mysqli_query() нужно два параметра передавать или же использовать ООП

Comment: Перевожу сообщение об ошибке `Внимание mysqli_query () ожидает, что по крайней мере 2 параметра, 1 указан`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Процедурный стиль**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name FROM Table")
```

**Объектно-ориентированный стиль** который Вам нужен

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM Table")
```

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

В вашем примере вы смешали Процедурный и Объектно-ориентированный стиль. Есть класс Database, так пусть у него в конструкторе или в функции `connectToDb()` будет создано подключенние к БД:

```
class Database {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = "admin";
    private $pass = "12345";
    private $db = "db2";
    protected $mysqliDB;

    function connectToDb() {

        $this->mysqliDB = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

        /* проверка соединения */
        if ($this->mysqliDB->connect_errno) {
            printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }
    }
    function closeConnection() {
        $this->mysqliDB->close();
    }
}
```

Класс Select и его функция `getRecordById`

```
function getRecordById($id) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->tabname WHERE id = '$id'";
    if ($result = $this->mysqliDB->query($query)) {
        ....
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Еще бы добавить контроль ошибок и было бы замечательно

Comment: Сделал так как вы написали, теперь вот что выводит Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in E:\OpenServer\domains\admin\models\database.php on line 11
Не удалось подключиться:

Comment: @vovaxxx, поправил код. Там в конструкторе mysqli нужно было добавить $this-> перед переменными. Но это можно было и так догадаться